# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am new to Python. I am trying to recognize text from images from TensorFlow. When I try to run `python gen.py` in the terminal, I am getting a `TypeError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen.py", line 287, in 
   for img_idx, (im, c, p) in enumerate(im_gen):
  File "gen.py", line 277, in generate_ims
   yield generate_im(random.choice(char_ims), num_bg_images)
  File "gen.py", line 239, in generate_im
   bg = generate_bg(num_bg_images)
  File "gen.py", line 226, in generate_bg
   bg = cv2.imread(fname, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) / 255.
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code can't open image on that path

```
bg = cv2.imread(fname, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) / 255
```

The cv2.imread method returned None.

It's better to get the image first

```
image = cv2.imread(fname, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
if image is not None:
    bg = image / 255
```

Also you can import the os module at the beginning to check that file exists

```
import os
# <your code...>
if !os.path.isfile(fname):
    raise Exception("File doesn't exist")

image = cv2.imread(fname, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
if image is not None:
    bg = image / 255
```